# Do an If statement relating to Excel Sheets existing

Tags: excel, powershell, worksheet

I want to be able to check if a Sheet or worksheet in Excel with name "ALPHA" (for example) exists or does not exist as part of my automated script.

My main goal is to be able to do something that functions like:

```
if ("ALPHA" exists) {Code A}

if ("ALPHA" does not exist) {Code B}
```

You know the standard If statement stuff

But I cant seem to figure out how to do it

I have Tried

```
$file = "$path\excel.xlsx"

$Exl = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$Exl.Visible = $false
$Exl.DisplayAlerts = $false

$wbk = $Exl.Workbooks.Open($file)
$wst = $wbk.worksheets | where {$_.name -eq "*ALPHA*"}

 If (Test-Path $wst) 

    {echo 1}

  Else {echo 2}
```

But all I get is:

```
Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
```

Part of the Requirements is that it needs to be able to work if Alpha is a variable from the

```
ForEach (Alpha in Bet)
```

And the the fact that there might be other Sheets than just Alpha, and I dont want to trigger the code just  by doing an "if -eq" or a "if -ne" affecting those sheets

---

**Thanks to @mklement0 for the clarification and answer**

It was much more simpler to implement than I thought possible

The Following is the Answer code that is what I was looking for:

```
 $wst = $wbk.worksheets | where {$_.name -like "*ALPHA*"}

 if ($wst) { Echo 1 }
 Else {Echo 2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, the only thing that needs to change is:

```
$wst = $wbk.worksheets | where {$_.name -eq "*ALPHA*"}

If (Test-Path $wst) { ... }
```

must be (note the use of `-like` instead of `-eq`, and the absence of `Test-Path`):

```
$wst = $wbk.worksheets | where {$_.name -like "*ALPHA*"}

if ($wst) { ... }
```

**To use *wildcard* (pattern) matching, you must use the dedicated `-like` operator, not `-eq`**.

If no worksheets match, `$null` is returned, so conditional `if ($wst)` will only evaluate to `$true` if *at least 1* worksheet was returned.
Thus, be aware that `$ws` may actually be an *array* of worksheets, if more than one matched the name pattern.

(The `Test-Path` cmdlet is designed to work with PowerShell *drive providers*, which do not come into play here.)

Comment: Holy crap, How'd I miss that... anyway I changed it to

Comment: Changed to  $wst = $wbk.worksheets | where {$_.name -like "*ALPHA*"}


..... but... still get ....Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null..... if the sheet DOESNT exist... but get the Else code Echo 2 response when the Alpha DOES exist.... isnt it supposed to be the other way round?

Comment: @AdilZia You're now missing the `*` wildcard characters from your pattern; also, as stated, _do not use_ `Test-Path`.

Comment: Thank you very much ... the Resulting code is .... $wst = $wbk.worksheets | where {$_.name -like "*ALPHA*"}   ...   
if ($wst) { Echo 1} Else {Echo 2}    .... and i Get 1 when it finds the sheet .. and 2 when no sheet .... thank you very much .... this was actually much simpler to implement than i was actually expecting

Comment: @AdilZia: Glad to hear it. Note that if you're looking for `"ALPHA"`, which is not a _pattern_ (no wildcard characters), `-eq` would have worked too.

Comment: Got it, Thank you very much